# Scroll Creation Pricing

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, magus, pricing

Now, I've read several threads that sound similar to this one, but none of them really touch on the question I have and I can't find a proper response to it. I am a Magus, using Spell-Scars to make "scrolls". The pricing is still the same as if using Scribe Scroll (12.5 × spell level × caster level). If I am crafting a 'Scroll of Shield' (Or any Level 1 spell that doesn't scale off of level, for that matter) at the lowest possible caster level, how much would this cost, and why? Because the way I see it from math, if I'm just crafting a level 1 spell at caster level 1, wouldn't it still just be 12 gold 5 silver? Or does it immediately get bumped up to 25 gold, even if I'm making it at the lowest possible level?

Comment: I've removed the second question. You're welcome to ask it, but separate questions have to be posted as separate question posts (otherwise they eventually get lost, hidden in a post that is tagged and titled for the first question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Price for "Scribing" a scroll is always equal to half of what it would cost to purchase the same scroll you are making.  For a caster/spell level 1 scroll (25 x spell level x caster level), that would be 25/2 which is 12.5 gold to scribe the scroll.  And since that is what Spell-Scars allows you to do, that is what it would cost.

As for the second part of the question; it would be the same effect either way, except that you don't get the benefit of casting the spell.  Thats a question for your GM, though as one myself, I would see no issue in it.

Comment: I absolutely misread a table on Paizo's site is where this confusion stems from (http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html Creating Scrolls, 2/3 down the page). I didn't realize it was the price of buying them. It was directly under the title of the section named "Creating Scrolls", so I read it and took it at face value. Complete mess-up on my part. Thanks very much for the clarification.